# Force typescript compile code with non-critical errors

Tags: typescript, eslint

Typescript works perfect since it tells you all errors you have in the code when compiling.

However, in development, this can be a bit annoying when you make a change to try like, for example, to comment a line.
An example working with eslint:
*Failed to compile.
*Line whatever. Variable X is declared but its value is never read.**

Is there a way to force Typescript compile with this kind of errors that don't affect the app's behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the `tsconfig.json` with:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  }
}
```

Additionally you can set [no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) eslint rule so that the errors would show in your IDE but typescript would still compile your code.

Or include it as a flag (`--noUnusedLocals`, `--noUnusedParameters`) in your build command in the `package.json`.

More info about flags in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: Thank you!

I want to add that  "noUnusedLocals": false and "noUnusedParameters": false is the default behavior.

For my problem, adding "no-unused-vars": "warn" worked. It allows to see the unused variables in the console while still letting the compiler compile without trouble.